# open jpg image in oracle form 10g using client_host

Tags: oracle, oracle10g, oracleforms

I want to display an image in oracle form 10g using client_host by windows photo viewer.

I use this code:

```
declare
b_file_name varchar2(255);
begin
b_file_name :='windows photo viewer C:\Users\batool\Pictures\aaa.jpg';
client_host(b_file_name);
end;
```

and that code worked fine, but the image is not displayed.

Comment: you may search for `webutil`

Comment: What do you mean, the "code worked fine"? I'm not sure what you expect to happen by running the command `windows photo viewer ...` on the client OS.